# Jquery UI: Animating remove class on callback of animating add class fails

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When some new list item is added I want it to 'blink' by animating adding a class and removing it after on the callback.

This is the code:

```
$li.addClass('new', 1000, function() {
    $li.removeClass('new', 500);
});
```

Css:

```
#galleries-list li {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #EEFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #99FFFF;  
    }
#galleries-list li.new {
    background-color: #DDFFBB;
    border: 1px solid #99FF66; 
    }
```

UPDATE:

I found what went wrong. When I removed the fadeOut it works. I have no idea why. Maybe you can check this and sent it to the jQuery UI dev's.

```
$('input, img', $li).fadeOut(150, function() {
  $gallery.set($li, name, 0); //Clears html and sets gallery name and image count
  $li.addClass('create', 2000, function() { $li.removeClass('create', 500); }); 
});
```

Comment: Aha! You `can` use callbacks in `addClass`. +1 for being more useful than the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Known bug** *This does not work in Safari 4, but it has been fixed in the yet unreleased (at the time of this writing) 1.8 version of jQuery UI.*

Sorry, I have removed my answer because your code is completely correct. However, even their demo for `addClass` does not work in Safari 4, but worked fine in Firefox 3.5.

**Update**: You can see [your code working here](http://jsbin.com/usayi), if you visit the page in Firefox 3.5:

Comment: When i make a callback function and log something it works.. I agree that it's not in the documentairy

Comment: Yes, I just noticed Safari won't work. Well then I'll won't use jQuery ui

Comment: @unknown, don't give up on it yet... I just sent a message to one of the core team members... Its a known bug that has been fixed in jQuery UI 1.8a2. As soon as 1.8 is released it will be fixed.

Comment: mm still Unknown, i should change that. 
I'll sit still and wait for it.

Comment: That works great! Thanks for all the help, i'll keep searching now why mine isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think addClass and removeClass have duration parameters.
http://docs.jquery.com/Addclass

You could try

li.addClass("new").animate({"opacity" : 1}, 500, function(){
     li.removeClass("new");
});

This will add the "new" class, then pause for half a second, then remove the class.

Comment: jQuery UI makes the duration option possible